# How hide text input by combobox

Tags: javascript, html

How hide

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control"  name="c_a" id="c_a" value="$"  >
```

when i select

```
<option value="img/p.png"  >Piad</option>
```

### in combobox

this form i used thank for evey one .

```
<form name="Form1" method="post" action="dashboard.php" id="Form1">


                              <div class="form-group input-group">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon" ><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="c_number" value="" placeholder="TEST@TEST"></div>

                             <div class="form-group input-group">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon" ><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="c_bab" value="" placeholder="Password"></div>


                              <div class="form-group input-group">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon" ><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="c_serail" value="" placeholder="0723228499" ></div>


                                     <div class="form-group input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" ><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></span>
                                   <input type="text"  class="form-control"  name="c_a" id="c_a" value="$"  ></div>

                                   <div class="form-group input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" ><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span>
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="c_point" value="" placeholder="اذا كان اليوزر تابع لمسوق او وكيل" ></div>

                                    <div class="form-group input-group">

                            <select name="c_status" id="c_status" size="1" class="form-control"  >


                                 <option value="img/p.png"  >Piad</option>
                                 <option value="img/un.png">unPiad</option>
                                 </select>
                                 </div>

                                 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="cards" value="ادخال" >



                                 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty basic function to do this would be:

```
    function hideElements() {
      var selected = document.getElementById('c_status').value;
      if (selected == 'img/p.png') {
        document.getElementById('c_a').style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('c_a').style.display = 'inline';
      }
    }
```

then you could add the following to your select box:

```
    <select name="c_status" id="c_status" size="1" class="form-control" onchange="hideElements(this);" >
```